# I cannot figure out why some methods and properties don't indicate like methods and properties in VS code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I cannot figure out why some methods and properties don't highlight (or other methods of indications) in the VS code.

For example (in my case):
Methods and properties of the event object don't indicate like methods and properties and it makes me being so confused and when I hover over them and then VS code says, "any" (what it means I've no idea).

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the extensions if there is a extension that might help you.
I don't know exactly what you need but you may want to check out some of these extensions:

- fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight
- debugpig.highlight
- vincaslt.highlight-matching-tag

These are some examples I found in the extensions off visual-studio-code (file->preference->extensions or Ctrl+Shift+X) and typing in: javascript highlight.